# Adding a Comma in between pagination in datatable

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using `datatables` and I need a comma in between the numbers in pagination.

This code works fine from the console but not from page, I tried using it many self invoking functions, but still its not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.dataTables_paginate>a.paginate_button').next('span').children('a.paginate_button').append(',');
});
```

Comment: Please post more of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use CSS and do not worry about JavaScript.

```css
.paginate_button:after {
    content: ", ";
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.paginate_button:last-child:after {
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="#" class="paginate_button">1</a>
    <a href="#" class="paginate_button">2</a> 
    <a href="#" class="paginate_button">3</a> 
    <a href="#" class="paginate_button">4</a> 
    <a href="#" class="paginate_button">5</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append ',' before drawing/initialising the datatable like this:

```
$('#dataTables_paginate').find('span').children('a').append(','); //'dataTables' is the ID of your datatable.
```

Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/53s39cab/2/) for the same. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is calling this code from Console..

Which ensures that the page and the Data Table has loaded.

But in document ready you are unsure whether the table has been populated.

So once you instantiate datatable

```
$("#TableID").dataTable();
//call your code after this

$(document).ready(function(){
$('div.dataTables_paginate>a.paginate_button')
    .next('span')
    .children('a.paginate_button')
    .append(',');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION**

Attach handler to [`draw`](http://datatables.net/reference/event/draw) event as shown below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table')
        .on( 'draw.dt', function () {
           $('div.dataTables_paginate>a.paginate_button')
              .next('span')
              .children('a.paginate_button')
               .append(',');
        });

    // DataTable initialization
    $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1pqycqp/) for code and demonstration.